# Opening saved game Stockfish

Tags: stockfish

I have saved PGN file from a file in Stockfish on mac, but when I open it the position of the pieces does not move. Why?

Comment: I've done it now and everything is working. Press on arrows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press on Arrows in order to run the moves:

[image]